# Tainted canvases may not be exported when using CSS background-image

Tags: javascript, css, canvas, cross-domain, html2canvas

I'm using html2canvas to generate an image from a set of HTML elements. However one of these elements has a `background-image` property with an image that's loaded from a different origin. This results in the canvas getting tainted when it's generating, failing my image generation with the following error

```
DOMException: Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on 'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be exported.
```

when trying to call `toDataUrl()` on the returned canvas.

The image has the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header set to `*` so I feel like it *should* work however the error is of course not giving me much to go on.

There are a lot of questions about loading images from different origins into canvases using `image.crossOrigin = 'anonymous'` but none mention images loaded as background-image using CSS so I'm wondering how to deal with this?

Comment: Test if your image truly passes CORS: Are you able to use `toDataURL` when you draw the image directly on an empty canvas (not as a background)? Also, have you set html2canvas's [useCORS](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/documentation.html) to true? If the problem persists maybe html2canvas doesn't check background images and you might have to layer an img under the div instead of using a background-image.

Answer (score 2):

Don't know if it's still an issue but I had the same issue with CSS background-image which generated me the same error.

Fixed it with the [html2canvas option](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/documentation.html) `useCORS: true`. Beside that it was also important to have the default value for the option `allowTaint` which is `false`